# No Puedo Listar *Ngfor angular, desde Observable firebase, metodo

Tags: angular, firebase, ngfor, response

Cuando quiero listar desde firebase me sale este error, la conexion con direbase, si esta funcionando, puedo registrar y loguearme con el mismo

En Consola si devuelve los datos

--En Consola--

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]

0

: 

{ano: '2022', descripcion: 'Descripcion Lorem', nombre: 'CISCO', id: 'Cnrbg6KNM015Ww321m1x'}

1

: 

{descripcion: 'JAVA', nombre: 'Desc', ano: '2022', id: 'mAgE6VfjZCczMWXoxXTF'}
```

pero cuando lo quiero listar sale error

```
<div *ngFor="let item of estudios ">
  <p>{{ item.nombre }}</p>
</div>
```

estudios.component.html:24 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'EstudiosComponent' component template).

Si lo hago asi si aparece la informacion

`<p>{{ estudios[0].nombre }}</p>`

--estudios.component.ts--

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.estudioService.getEstudios().subscribe((estudios) => {
      console.log(estudios);
      this.estudios = estudios;
    });
  }  


--estudio.service.ts--
 getEstudios(): Observable<Estudio[]> {
    const placeRef = collection(this.firestore, 'estudios');
    return collectionData(placeRef, { idField: 'id' }) as Observable<Estudio[]>;
  } 
--estudio.ts Interface--
 export interface Estudio {
  id?: string;
  ano: string;
  nombre: string;
  descripcion: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadir el módulo `BrowserModule` a tu aplicación:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Si lo tengo  en app.modules.ts

Comment: ¿Tienes varios módulos?

Comment: Si,uso un ngfor para consumir una api y si carga., Pero es una estructura basica